# How to place the definition title in square brackets (instead of paranthesis)

Tags: theorems

This question is asked about placing theorem title in square bracket:

[How to place the theorem title in square brackets (instead of paranthesis)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371014/how-to-place-the-theorem-title-in-square-brackets-instead-of-paranthesis)

How can I do the same for definitions, too?

Comment: Doesn't my answer below do what you want?

Comment: @Arzigoglu: Sorry for such a delay to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer you linked, define

```
\newtheoremstyle{defbrakets}% Name
  {}% space above
  {}% space below
  {\normalfont}% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% head font
  {.}% punctuation after head
  { }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
  {\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec
```

and then use

```
\theoremstyle{defbrakets}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\thmheadbrackets#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont[#3]}}}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{brakets}% Name
  {}% space above
  {}% space below
  {\itshape}% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% head font
  {.}% punctuation after head
  { }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
  {\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec

\newtheoremstyle{defbrakets}% Name
  {}% space above
  {}% space below
  {\normalfont}% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% head font
  {.}% punctuation after head
  { }% space after head (has to be space or dimension!)
  {\thmheadbrackets{#1}{#2}{#3}}% head spec

\theoremstyle{brakets}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{defbrakets}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[title]
    theorem's body
\end{thm}

\begin{dfn}[title]
    definition's body
\end{dfn}

\end{document}
```

[image]