# Using Chinese brackets rather than Latin ones

Tags: theorems

I want to replace the normal brackets `(` and `)` by Chinese ones. There is a solution for this problem with `amsthm` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371022/18561), but I cannot load this package since there is a problem with `\openbox` being already defined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{theorem}

{\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{principle}{Principle}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{principle}[Theta-Criterion]
\begin{itemize}
\item Each theta-role is assigned to exactly one argument position.
\item Every phrase in an argument position receives exactly one theta"=role.
\end{itemize}
\end{principle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are "Chinese" brackets? Are they just a fancy term for *square* brackets, i.e., `[` and `]`?

Comment: The `theorem` package is largely obsolete.

Comment: I need it for a Chinese book. What I would have liked is a global replacement of all brackets by Chinese brackets. I have been fighting for citation brackets in \cite and now theorems. Some years ago I have been told that the general solution is impossible.

Comment: Which other package is breaking `amsthm`? Does changing the order in which you load packages fix it?

Comment: It is a complex book class loading tons of packages. https://github.com/langsci/177 I tried to load amsthm at the very beginning of this class and this worked. Let's see whether I can find a way to load the package.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `amsthm`, which I recommend, at least use `ntheorem`. The `theorem` package is largely obsolete and much less flexible.

It's not difficult to define new styles for `ntheorem`, although one needs to fiddle with `\makeatletter`. I just copied the definitions for the `plain` and the `break` styles and replaced the parentheses with brackets. Why Chinese? OK, instead of `(##3)` I used `{[##3]}` because the brackets interfere with the scanning of optional arguments in the `plain` case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{plain-brackets}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ {[##3]}\theorem@separator]}

\newtheoremstyle{break-brackets}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ {[##3]}\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{plain-brackets}
\newtheorem{principleA}{Principle}

\theoremstyle{break-brackets}
\newtheorem{principleB}{Principle}

\begin{document}

\section{Plain style}

\begin{principleA}[Theta-Criterion]\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Each theta-role is assigned to exactly one argument position.
\item Every phrase in an argument position receives exactly one theta-role.
\end{itemize}
\end{principleA}

\section{Break style}

\begin{principleB}[Theta-Criterion]
\begin{itemize}
\item Each theta-role is assigned to exactly one argument position.
\item Every phrase in an argument position receives exactly one theta-role.
\end{itemize}
\end{principleB}

\end{document}
```

Why do I propose two solutions? Just look at the picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried to integrate this into a complex book but this resulted in a strange message: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.1 \chapter{前言}
                
?

Comment: @StefanMüller There can be so many causes… For instance, did you tell us you're writing in Chinese?

Comment: Yes. And I wanted to have Chinese brackets. =:-) I know this cannot be debugged this way. ...

Comment: @StefanMüller Chinese brackets are at unicode codepoint U+3000, 「」『』【】〔〕〖〗〚〛etc, if that helps. You will need a font that has them, of course. 〈〉《》

Comment: Thanks! I have a complete book in Chinese. Having the brackets in the main text is not the problem. The problem is to get the brackets in all the nice things that latex packages produce. I found a temporary way to load amsthm by loading it in the book class (which I am not supposed to touch ...)

Comment: I got the amsthm solution to work. Well, almost. I does not cope with the itemize environment. I need the \mbox{} to get the itemize to the next line. Can this be integrated into the code, somehow?

Comment: I guess I much prefer a quick hack of theorem.sty to get the brackets redone in a way that allows me to keep the rest of the book constant. Without any \mbox insertions and so on.